# OP un-accepts somebody else's answer and accepts yours

Tags: discussion, general-reference

Is there a name for the phenomenon of an OP switching approval from one answer to another?

(I am not saying or asking whether, or when,  this might be a good idea)

Is there a badge for writing [a certain number of] answers, after someone else's answer has been accepted, and then the OP switches to accepting yours?

Comment: [*Premature acceptance?*](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307)

Comment: On another note, acceptance votes are not serious, really. Accepting an answer is a special upvote that the OP has. As much as explaining upvotes isn't required, explaining accept votes or anything alike isn't either. However, if you noticed [rage unaccepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166048/new-phenomenon-rage-unaccepting?s=1|5.8546), please do flag for moderator attention.

Comment: @J.R. Ha! Also occasionally triggered by bounties, in which case I wholeheartedly approve; I love successful bounties that produce great new answers :)

Comment: This seems like it would be more appropriate on SE Meta.

Comment: @Cat I don't remember sending people to the main meta a lot. It only happened in bug reports that affected most SEs. If all of the questions that were better there were migrated from here, we'd been left with less than a hundred meta posts. ;)

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M what? This question isn't "does ELL have a term for this?"... It is completely possible that SE has a name for this that no one on ELL knows.

Comment: @Cat yes,  but as the OP chose to write in our meta, we have to have a good reason to send it there, *I think*. Questions that pertain to a specific SEs do get closed there, but it doesn't work the other way around. I meant that it *is* a better fit for meta.SE, but it's unlikely that it'll get migrated.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M I don't see where I said it should be migrated... I only mentioned that it "seems like it would be more appropriate" there...

Answer (score 3):

If there is a name for this, it must be somewhat obscure; I've not run across any such thing in my time on various metas. It's just referred to as unaccepting one and accepting the other, or changing where the checkmark is, or whatever seems idiomatic.

There is no badge for this. The closest is Populist, given when your answer has score of 23+ and more than double that of the accepted answer with a score of 11+, but that's really more the reverse, since if your answer is accepted before you get the badge, you're no longer eligible on that answer.

Basically, it's behavior that's already rewarded well enough by the rep system, for the most part, so badges do not seem necessary. (They might also encourage badgering* the asker for a change, which is definitely a very bad thing to have happen.)

<sub>**No pun intended. Originally.*</sub>

Comment: Hadn't thought about the "badgering" aspect.  The upside is that it would encourage people to continue trying for a better answer even after one has been accepted.  This is different than the populist badge, as it has nothing to do with how many  upvotes one has.  I have had answers accepted with zero upvotes, and some of my most popular answers were not accepted. The point is not points (pun intended), but striving to serve the OP (and future readers) better by offering a better answer.

Comment: I wonder how many questioners actually know that they **can** cancel an Accept, and then Accept a different answer. Yes, they are advised not to accept 'prematurely' (both in the hints for new users, and by responders) but are they informed about the unaccept/accept option?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: Not sure, but the tooltip says right there that they can click again to undo, so it's not some obscure feature buried in five layers of menus….

Comment: Right. That should be good enough. Of course, I would never see the tooltip, having no mouse, and thus no way to hover (I use an iPhone.) Oddly, many OPs need coaching as to how to accept in the first place. But that's off-topic.